# What is "stack hog"

Tags: linux, kernel

What does "stack hog" means when talking about Linux kernel?

I read this notion on some linux kernel books(Professional Linux Kernel Architecture by Wolfgang Mauerer), but what exactly does "stack hog" means? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  A 'stack hog' will be a process that uses an excessive amount of stack space — almost certainly.  How much research did you do with Google (or your favourite search engine)?  For example, 'linux stack hog' seems to collect quite a number of questions on the Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stack hog" is an informal name used to describe functions that use significant amounts of automatic storage (AKA "the stack"). What exactly counts as "hogging" varies by the execution environment: in general, kernel-level functions have tighter limits on the stack space - just a few kilobytes, so a function considered a "stack hog" in kernel mode may become a "good citizen" in user mode.

A common reason for a function to become a stack hog is allocating buffers or other arrays in the automatic memory. This is more convenient, because you do not need to remember to free the memory and check the results of the allocation. You could also save some CPU cycles on the allocation itself. The downside is a possibility of overflowing the stack, wich results in panic for kernel-level programs. That is why a common remedy of "stack hogging" is moving some of your buffers into dynamic memory.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel uses 4K stacks. Using an inordinate amount of that small space is considered being a hog. If you are "lazy" and allocate a buffer on the stack or have a function with a large number of parameters that is being a hog.

The stack must hold any sequence of calls needed to service a system call as well as any interrupt handlers that may be called. So it is very important to conserve stack space.

Comment: linux kernel uses 8K of kernel stack by every process by default